# Is there a method, such as group by, that will allow me to get the min/max preceding values in a group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the following data table I am trying to return the `tlow` and `thigh` columns.  I already have the logic for the inverted filter(~) figured out but I am struggling with how to determine the example values.

dx alternates between periods of True and False.  When it is True I want to return the preceding maximum value of `lw` within that group of Trues to `tlow`.

```
fltr = pvdata['dx'].astype(bool)
pvdata.loc[fltr,'tlow'] = #preceding max of lw
```

The actual filter is slightly more complicated is why I have it set to its own variable.

Vice versa for when dx is False.  I want to return the preceding minimum value of `hgh` within that group of Falses to `thigh`.

```
pvdata.loc[~fltr,'thigh'] = #preceding min of HGH
```

[image]

My best attempt so far was to use `.shift()` to compare values and the `.ffill()` to carry them forward, but I cant figure out how to compare over the entire True/False period given that it is of varying length.

I know this is possible with a loop, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid that.

Comment: `df.groupby(groups).cummin()` and `.cummax()`, where `groups=df['dx'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()`.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). You might need to use `print(pvdata)`.

Comment: Quang Hoang, that's way too easy, thank you.  I will see if I can get it to work.